# Set GPO through Registry Value using C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry, gpo, dword

I try to restrict the access to removable storage devices through the Group Policy `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access\All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access`

Accoring to [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) the corresponding registry (and path) is setting a DWORD to 1 (enabled) or 0 (disabled) in `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices!Deny_All`

So far so good. When I try to change these settings through the Group Policy Editor everythings works fine. Even if the removable storage device is plugged in the policy works instantly.

When I try to change the value through the registry itself or using a self-written C# program it doesn't work the policy stays enabled (or disabled).

My C# Code

```
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\RemovableStorageDevices", true))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                key.SetValue("Deny_All", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Even if I try to update all polices through `gpupdate /force` nothing. It's quite the opposite, the old value is set in the registry regardless of whether I'm setting it through hand or through my program. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: I'm just using the code from [meziantou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2996339/meziantou) from [How to Programmatically Set GPO to Not Configured or Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469447/how-to-programmatically-set-gpo-to-not-configured-or-disabled)