# Group Policy - Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, gpo

I am trying to set GroupPolicy value using the following code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673417/5436341):

```
[ComImport, Guid("EA502722-A23D-11d1-A7D3-0000F87571E3")]
internal class GPClass
{
}

[ComImport, Guid("EA502723-A23D-11d1-A7D3-0000F87571E3"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IGroupPolicyObject
{
    uint New([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string domainName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string displayName, uint flags);

    uint OpenDSGPO([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string path, uint flags);

    uint OpenLocalMachineGPO(uint flags);

    uint OpenRemoteMachineGPO([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string computerName, uint flags);

    uint Save([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool machine, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool add, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid extension, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid app);

    uint Delete();

    uint GetName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder name, int maxLength);

    uint GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder name, int maxLength);

    uint SetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string name);

    uint GetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder path, int maxPath);

    uint GetDSPath(uint section, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder path, int maxPath);

    uint GetFileSysPath(uint section, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder path, int maxPath);

    uint GetRegistryKey(uint section, out IntPtr key);

    uint GetOptions(out uint options);

    uint SetOptions(uint options, uint mask);

    uint GetType(out IntPtr gpoType);

    uint GetMachineName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder name, int maxLength);

    uint GetPropertySheetPages(out IntPtr pages);
}


public enum GroupPolicySection
{
    Root = 0,
    User = 1,
    Machine = 2,
}

public abstract class GroupPolicyObject
{
    protected const int MaxLength = 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// The snap-in that processes .pol files
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Guid RegistryExtension = new Guid(0x35378EAC, 0x683F, 0x11D2, 0xA8, 0x9A, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xBB, 0xCF, 0xA2);

    /// <summary>
    /// This application
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Guid LocalGuid = new Guid(GetAssemblyAttribute<GuidAttribute>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Value);

    protected IGroupPolicyObject Instance = null;

    static T GetAssemblyAttribute<T>(ICustomAttributeProvider assembly) where T : Attribute
    {
        object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true);
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
            return null;

        return (T)attributes[0];
    }

    internal GroupPolicyObject()
    {
        Instance = GetInstance();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        var result = Instance.Save(true, true, RegistryExtension, LocalGuid);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error saving machine settings");
        }

        result = Instance.Save(false, true, RegistryExtension, LocalGuid);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error saving user settings");
        }
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        var result = Instance.Delete();
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error deleting the GPO");
        }
        Instance = null;
    }

    public RegistryKey GetRootRegistryKey(GroupPolicySection section)
    {
        IntPtr key;
        var result = Instance.GetRegistryKey((uint)section, out key);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to get section '{0}'", Enum.GetName(typeof(GroupPolicySection), section)));
        }

        var handle = new SafeRegistryHandle(key, true);
        return RegistryKey.FromHandle(handle, RegistryView.Default);
    }

    public abstract string GetPathTo(GroupPolicySection section);

    protected static IGroupPolicyObject GetInstance()
    {
        var concrete = new GPClass();
        return (IGroupPolicyObject)concrete;
    }
}

public class GroupPolicyObjectSettings
{
    public readonly bool LoadRegistryInformation;
    public readonly bool Readonly;

    public GroupPolicyObjectSettings(bool loadRegistryInfo = true, bool readOnly = false)
    {
        LoadRegistryInformation = loadRegistryInfo;
        Readonly = readOnly;
    }

    private const uint RegistryFlag = 0x00000001;
    private const uint ReadonlyFlag = 0x00000002;

    internal uint Flag
    {
        get
        {
            uint flag = 0x00000000;
            if (LoadRegistryInformation)
            {
                flag |= RegistryFlag;
            }

            if (Readonly)
            {
                flag |= ReadonlyFlag;
            }

            return flag;
        }
    }
}

public class ComputerGroupPolicyObject : GroupPolicyObject
{
    public readonly bool IsLocal;

    public ComputerGroupPolicyObject(GroupPolicyObjectSettings options = null)
    {
        options = options ?? new GroupPolicyObjectSettings();
        var result = Instance.OpenLocalMachineGPO(options.Flag);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to open local machine GPO");
        }
        IsLocal = true;
    }

    public ComputerGroupPolicyObject(string computerName, GroupPolicyObjectSettings options = null)
    {
        options = options ?? new GroupPolicyObjectSettings();
        var result = Instance.OpenRemoteMachineGPO(computerName, options.Flag);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to open GPO on remote machine '{0}'", computerName));
        }
        IsLocal = false;
    }

    public static void SetPolicySetting(string registryInformation, string settingValue, RegistryValueKind registryValueKind)
    {
        string valueName;
        GroupPolicySection section;
        string key = Key(registryInformation, out valueName, out section);

        // Thread must be STA
        Exception exception = null;
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var gpo = new ComputerGroupPolicyObject();
                using (RegistryKey rootRegistryKey = gpo.GetRootRegistryKey(section))
                {
                    // Data can't be null so we can use this value to indicate key must be delete
                    if (settingValue == null)
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subKey = rootRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(key, true))
                        {
                            if (subKey != null)
                            {
                                subKey.DeleteValue(valueName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subKey = rootRegistryKey.CreateSubKey(key))
                        {
                            subKey.SetValue(valueName, settingValue, registryValueKind);
                        }
                    }
                }

                gpo.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
            }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        if (exception != null)
            throw exception;
    }

    public static object GetPolicySetting(string registryInformation)
    {
        string valueName;
        GroupPolicySection section;
        string key = Key(registryInformation, out valueName, out section);

        // Thread must be STA
        object result = null;
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var gpo = new ComputerGroupPolicyObject();
            using (RegistryKey rootRegistryKey = gpo.GetRootRegistryKey(section))
            {
                // Data can't be null so we can use this value to indicate key must be delete
                using (RegistryKey subKey = rootRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(key, true))
                {
                    if (subKey == null)
                    {
                        result = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = subKey.GetValue(valueName);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return result;
    }

    private static string Key(string registryInformation, out string value, out GroupPolicySection section)
    {
        // Parse parameter of format HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization!NoChangingSoundScheme
        string[] split = registryInformation.Split('!');
        string key = split[0];
        string hive = key.Substring(0, key.IndexOf('\\'));
        key = key.Substring(key.IndexOf('\\') + 1);

        value = split[1];

        if (hive.Equals(@"HKLM", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            || hive.Equals(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            section = GroupPolicySection.Machine;
        }
        else
        {
            section = GroupPolicySection.User;
        }
        return key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retrieves the file system path to the root of the specified GPO section.
    ///     The path is in UNC format.
    /// </summary>
    public override string GetPathTo(GroupPolicySection section)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(MaxLength);
        var result = Instance.GetFileSysPath((uint)section, sb, MaxLength);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to retrieve path to section '{0}'", Enum.GetName(typeof(GroupPolicySection), section)));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And using it as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ComputerGroupPolicyObject.SetPolicySetting(@"HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\HomeGroup!DisableHomeGroup", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    ComputerGroupPolicyObject.SetPolicySetting(@"HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\HomeGroup!DisableHomeGroup", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    ComputerGroupPolicyObject.SetPolicySetting(@"HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\HomeGroup!DisableHomeGroup", null, RegistryValueKind.Unknown);
}
```

This is working perfectly when I am trying to set a single value. But when I am trying to set multiple values one by one, I am seeing the below error at SetPolicySetting function call:

```
Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)
```

Somewhere the handle to GP is not getting disposed properly. I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone help please.

Comment: I'm guessing that although not documented, the `IGroupPolicyObject` can only be used once and must be destroyed using `IUnknown.Release` (you don't call this directly from C#). Therefore your `GroupPolicyObject` class must implement `IDisposable` and must call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Instance);` on dispose. You should also ideally have a message loop on your STA thread, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/14868997 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25188601/14868997

Comment: @Charlieface, as you suggested, I made GroupPolicyObject class must implement IDisposable and call Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Instance) in the Dispose() method. But I see that the Dispose() method is never executed. What am I missing here?

Comment: It obviously needs `using` in order to call `Dispose()`.