How to block/allow USB storage devices using C#?
I need to enable/disable the USB storage devices on the Windows machine programmatically. But I want to disable/enable it in real-time as well, I mean let's say if a USB storage device is connected to a PC and I run my code to disable it, it should disable/block it immediately (not on plug-out and then plug in). It should also not allow other USB devices as well until I run code to unblock/allow them.
I can manually achieve it by changing the local group policy like the below.

I have also noticed that when I change the above settings manually it changes the registry key Deny_All to 1 or 0, but when I change the registry key it doesn't; work without reinserting the device.

Changing the registry below also blocks/unblocks USB storage devices, but the problem with this solution is that it doesn't block/unblock the already inserted device.

So my question is how can use I enable/disable USB storage devices immediately? OR is there a way to refresh the settings after changing the registry value directly so that it considers it immediately?
PS: I don't want to use any third-party exe and WMI. I am ok with PInvoke and running the cmd process or so.
Edit As has been suggested in the below answer, I have tried the same steps with the code below, But its still not working as expected. I am adding my code below for reference.
class Program
{
    private enum RefreshPolicyOptions
    {
        RP_FORCE = 1,
        RP_SYNC
    }

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern bool RefreshPolicyEx(bool bMachine, RefreshPolicyOptions dwOptions);

    static void Main()
    {

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Refreshing group policy...");
            bool flag = RefreshPolicyEx(true, RefreshPolicyOptions.RP_FORCE);
            Console.WriteLine("Group policy refreshed: " + flag);
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying WMI: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}


whats the reason behind no WMI but p/invoke  is okay?

It’s been told by seniors who are working on this product from decades. I can’t challenge them at this moment, they said they have faced lot of issues in past with MWI @RandRandom

Why not use a Powershell Group Policy script? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

@jdweng sorry I am new to this. Can you please let me know how to implement it in C# code?

@jdweng I am getting an error when running  Set-GPRegistryValue in Powershell. Set-GPRegistryValue : The term 'Set-GPRegistryValue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

Do you have the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows installed as described in the first paragraph of GroupPolicy?  (You can't install RSAT on computers that are running Home or Standard editions of Windows. You can install RSAT only on Professional or Enterprise editions of the Windows client operating system)

I NEED TO RUN THIS CODE ON MANY CUSTOMERS'S MACHINES, SO ADDING NEW FEATURE IS NOT RECOMMENDED @user246821

Please re-read my previous comment. It is a response to your comment: The term 'Set-GPRegistryValue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Also, if you haven't already done so, read the information in the URLs.

my question is If I am changing the registry value then why is it not being considered?

The following may be of interest: gpupdate

The following may be of interest: Group Policy overview.

According to Group Policy Processing: Group Policy for computer settings is applied when the computer starts. Group Policy is applied at log on for users...After initial processing of Group Policy...the system periodically applies (refreshes) Group Policy in the background...By default, a refresh occurs every 90 minutes. The system might add a random time of up to 30 minutes to the refresh interval...

@user246821 tried gpupdate /force as well after setting the registry but this also didn’t work as per my expectations

What OS are you using.  The PS cmdlet should work in both Win 10 and Win 11 according to the documentation.

It’s windows 10 @jdweng

I don't think RSAT is installed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2022-ps  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

@jdweng I need to disable/enable on customers's machines. so I don't think we could install RSAT

RSAT should be installed on Win10 and Win11.  Not sure why it isn't working on your machine.  You may not have all the admin permissions to perform Group Policy.  Usually companies only allow some admins to change Group Policies.

It appears that this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469447/how-to-programmatically-set-gpo-to-not-configured-or-disabled and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834069/how-to-change-group-policy-via-command-line

Also see Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server

The Group Policy API has two functions to apply changes immediately. The first one is the RefreshPolicy function. The documentation says:

The RefreshPolicy function causes policy to be applied immediately on the client computer. To apply policy and specify the type of refresh that should occur, you can call the extended function RefreshPolicyEx.

Despite it says that it applies changes immediately, it doesn't!
To me, the API checks if there are changes caused from the group policy editor. If so, it applies the changes immediately. In your case, you change the group policy setting from the registry. So, this doesn't generate a group policy change event to be detected by the RefreshPolicy.
The API provides us with an extended version: RefreshPolicyEx.
This function takes a second parameter, dwOptions, which specifies the type of policy refresh to apply. This parameter can be given the constant RP_FORCE.

RP_FORCE
Reapply all policies even if no policy change was detected. Note that if there are any client-side extensions that can be applied at boot or logon time, (for example, an application installation extension), the extensions are re-applied at the next boot or logon, even if no policy change is detected.

Calling the extended version as follows immediately applied the changes and blocked the all USB storage devices opened by File Explorer on my computer.
RefreshPolicyEx(FALSE, RP_FORCE);

The PInvoke signature is below.
[Flag]
private enum RefreshPolicyOptions
{
     RP_FORCE = 1,
     RP_SYNC
}

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi)]
private static extern bool RefreshPolicyEx(bool bMachine, RefreshPolicyOptions dwOptions); 

Here is the demo program that I use.
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BlockUnblockRemovableStorageDevices
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        private enum RefreshPolicyOptions
        {
            RP_FORCE = 1,
            RP_SYNC
        }

        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        private static extern bool RefreshPolicyEx(bool bMachine, RefreshPolicyOptions dwOptions);

         
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlockRemovableStorageDevices(true);
        }
        
        private static void BlockRemovableStorageDevices(bool block)
        {
            RegistryKey removableStorageDevicesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\RemovableStorageDevices");
            if (removableStorageDevicesKey != null)
            {
                removableStorageDevicesKey.SetValue("Deny_All", block ? 1 : 0);
                removableStorageDevicesKey.Close();
                ApplyGroupPolicySettings();
            }
        }
        private static void ApplyGroupPolicySettings()
        {
            bool res = RefreshPolicyEx(false, RefreshPolicyOptions.RP_FORCE);
            if (!res)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            res = RefreshPolicyEx(true, RefreshPolicyOptions.RP_FORCE);
            if (!res)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}

There is an important point. When you configure this setting from gpedit, it creates the registry key and its value under the key itself.  And if it is set to disabled, for example, it tries to sets the value repeatedly to the value configured by it (This sometimes even causes errors to reading to and writing from the value). Thus, before setting the registry value manually, don't alter the setting inside gpedit and leave as not configured as in below.


I changed the registry value Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\Deny_All to 1 and then called RefreshPolicyEx, but it didn't block the USB storage device.

Set bMachine to TRUE if you change a computer policy. In my case, it was a user policy, so I set it to FALSE.

yes I did with run with TRUE

can you test your changes with the registry that I have mentioned

I tested it before and it was working correctly. Now, I am facing a subtle behaviour that I cannot set the registry value. Whenever I set the value to 1, something resets it to 0. In my computer, the corresponding key is in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices.

cant you find Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices on your machine?

I was setting the user policy setting. Now, I found the computer policy setting in the key you pointed out and set it to 1. When I call the function as in the answer, it blocks. It works, maybe because I run it as administrator. Can you run the app as admin? And check aslo the return value of the function? Also make sure the registry value is set correctly.

which key are you setting? and yes I am running my C# code as an admin. I am editing the question to provide you my code.

@VivekNuna can you take a look at the updated answer? With all the above conditions are satisfied, I can block/unblock USBs without any problem now.

I think, this is incorrect removableStorageDevicesKey.SetValue("Deny_All", block ? 1 : 0); it should be removableStorageDevicesKey.SetValue("Deny_All", block ? 0 : 1); and which .net framework are you targetting to?

When Deny_All becomes 1, the setting becomes active and it blocks the RSDs. So, the former is the correct one. I am using .Net 8 Console App. Read the last paragraph. I think it is the reason why it is not running on your PC. gpedit shouldn't mess up with the manual setting.

yes but you are caling BlockRemovableStorageDevices(false); so Deny_All will be set to 0

Oh, it was just for example. I had previously blocked the RSDs, so I unblocked them. You can change it to true.

I think you missed one of the important point, I mentioned in the question that I want to block the device immediately even if it's plugged in. I don't want to plug out and then plug in to block it.

I understood you correctly but I don't think that you've tried the last demo program. Take a look at this video.

Its not working as expected on my Windows 11 machine

It definitely would be not working.

I want this to be working on windows 11 as well.

My machine is also Windows 11.

Why is the same code not working for me, I’m really curious and frustrated

Did you set the setting in gpedit as not configured, which is default value?

Yes, it was set as not configured

Do we need to call RefreshPolicyEx with both true and false, as it’s in your code

Not strictly required but I recommend it to refresh both computer and user policies as described by the documentation.

I’ll try the same tomorrow and let you know

One more question, in my organisation they have blocked USB devices. But my my PC there is no value set for SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices. Also policy group editor shows not configured for the removals devices. I am just wondering how would they have blocked usb devices on our machine. Do you have any idea? Also the USBSTOR value is also 3 not 4

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have tried your solution, but it doesn't block the USB devices when the data transfer is in progress. and it starts behaving weirdly after this

and it blocks USB on my Windows 10 machine but does not work on my Windows 11 pro machine when the USB device is connected. I don't think you have windows 11 machine

Note that you have already found how to block/unblock USB devices, my answer only gives the solution to refresh Group Policy. The blocking/unblocking part comes from you. And, I have definetely a Windows 11 machine. It is also Pro edition. Your solution actually works pretty well on my machine. I don't understand why it is not running on yours. Maybe you should search for a more low-level solution such as writing kernel driver. I think it will be the most robust solution. Also, I have put a chat link. We could chat there.

your solution is not working on my Windows 11 machine, so it means it doesn't answer my question, simple. It doesn't block the USB device immediately.

Are you ok? I don't claim that this answer works for you!? We all together got that it isn't working for you, right? Just stop chatting with me here and find your solution that works on your system. Don't reply anymore.
